# How to change React Native style color, based on data condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, react-native

I am new to react native.

I am developing a simple quiz function inside an app. Developed an api that returns question, answers and the rightAnswer boolean,
Sort of this :

```
 {
   "question:"Demo question",
   "answer": [
               {
                   "rightAnswer": true,
                   "option": "demo answer 1"
               },
               {
                   "rightAnswer": false,
                   "option": "demo answer 2"
               },
               {
                   "rightAnswer": false,
                   "option": "demo answer 3"
               }
           ]
         }
```

The purpose of the rightAnswer field is to verify user's answer weather its right or wrong.

Demonstrating the quiz to user like this in React Native

```
            <Text> {quizArray.question}  </Text>
                    
                    
                    {quizArray.answer.map((r,index)=>
                    <TouchableHighlight key={r._id}
                          style={[
                            styles.listItem,
                            { backgroundColor: selectBtn === index ? '#da1c5c' : '#fff' }
                            

                          ]}
                        onPress={()=>{
                          setRightAnswer(r.rightAnswer)
                          setSelectBtn(index)
                        }}/>
```

setRightAnswer is my state.

I have a submit button that sets scores by verifying the answer like this

```
                    <SmallRound 
                        text= "submit"
                        onPress={async()=>{
                                      try{
                                        if(rightAnswer) setScore(score+10)
                                        else(setScore(score+0)
                                       }catch (error) {
                                         alert(error.message)
                                         }
                                  }}
                     />
```

What I want is after pressing my submit button I want my answer which has rightAnswer==true to have a border color of, let's say, green.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
            <Text> {quizArray.question}  </Text>
          
                    {quizArray.answer.map((r,index)=>
                    <TouchableHighlight key={r._id}
                          style={[
                            styles.listItem,
                            { backgroundColor: selectBtn === index ? '#da1c5c' : '#fff' },
{r.rightAnswer && selectBtn === index ? borderColor: 'green' : borderColor: 'red'}
                            
                          ]}
                        onPress={()=>{
                          setRightAnswer(r.rightAnswer)
                          setSelectBtn(index)
                        }}/>
```

I think you want to change the way you add to your score too

```
setScore(score + 10)
```

Comment: my bad, I actually my setScore the way you shown, what I wanted to know, how to show user right answer by bordering out the touchableHighlight after pressing another submit button, not the touchableHighlight

Comment: I see, maybe make another state variable isSubmitted and set it to true after they submit and then do it like I wrote, except check that  isSubmitted is also true in addition to it being r.rightAnswer and selectBtn === index.